# Chi Square Statistic in R

Tags: r, statistics

If I know the p-value I want and the degrees of freedom, can I get the chi square statistic from R?

I have the same question for a T Statistic, a Z statistic, and an F Statistic?

I basically want to be able to grab these numbers as if I had a lookup table.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics (math) not programming.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the quantile function:

```
p <- 0.2
df <- 10
qchisq(p, df)
#[1] 6.179079
```

There are quantile functions in R for the other distributions, too.

**Edit**:

As Ben Bolker points out, you are probably interested in P(X > x), which you can calculate like this:

```
qchisq(p, df, lower.tail=FALSE)
#[1] 13.44196
```

or equivalently:

```
qchisq(1-p, df)
#[1] 13.44196
```

Comment: I think if the OP wants a critical value they will actually want `qchisq(1-p,df)`; for two-tailed critical values, they will want (e.g.) `qnorm(1-p/2)`.

Comment: @BenBolker I agree, but, as always, if they want to use R for statistics they should understand the statistics first.

Comment: Fair enough.  I would divide my comment in two: the first half (use `1-p` instead of `p`) is IMO required to prevent the OP from making a serious mistake; the second half (two-tailed tests) is optional.